# ko.validation.group not always up to date with displayed errors

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have a view model with an error collection that I am binding to an ASP.NET MVC style validation summary. The problem is that the error collection is not always up to date with the current state of the model.

```
function CostEditViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.description = ko.observable().extend({ required: { message: "Please enter the description", params: true } });
    self.amount = ko.observable()
        .extend({ required: { message: "Please enter the amount", params: true } })
        .extend({ number: { message: "The amount is not valid", params: true } });
    self.displayErrors = ko.observable(false);
    self.errors = ko.validation.group(self);

    self.add = function() {
        self.edit(new Cost({ Description: '', Amount: '' } ));
    };

    self.edit = function(cost) {
        self.description(cost.Description());
        self.amount(cost.Amount());
        self.displayErrors(false);

        self.description.isModified(false);
        self.amount.isModified(false);
    };

    self.save = function() {
        if (self.isValid()) {
            DoAjaxSave();
        } else {
            self.displayErrors(true);
        }
    };
}
```

And then I bind errors to a UL

```
<div class="alert alert-error" data-bind="visible: displayErrors() && errors().length > 0">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: errors">
        <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The problem is that the errors that are displayed in the validation summary are not always up to date. If I trigger an error on amount the correct error is in the collection, but if I trigger the other error for amount it doesn't change what is in the errors collection even though it does display the correct error next to the field. To get the correct collection of errors one field has to change state between valid and not valid. If a field changes from one invalid state to another invalid state the errors collection is not updated.

Here is a fiddle I have created to demonstrate the example.

http://jsfiddle.net/e4LHV/2/

Comment: Could you try and create a [jsfiddle](www.jsfiddle.net) and illustrate your problem? I would like to play around with the code, if that's ok.

Comment: Here is the simplest fiddle I could make to demonstrate the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/e4LHV/2/

Comment: @AdrianBrand your fiddle is working fine, i can't see any issue in the fiddle you created, is there anything i am missing ?

Comment: @JCN - Try entering no value for amount, and then an invalid number. The validation group shows stale error message.

Comment: @JCN - If the amount field is not valid then triggering the other invalid state does not update the error collection. One field has to change between valid and invalid before the collection gets updated. Just hit the save button and you will get both of the required validators firing. Then change the amount field to be text. The message next to the amount changes but the error collection does not. Then enter the description and the collection will update.

Comment: If anyone else is experiencing this issue the this fixes the issue.

https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation/pull/248

Comment: new url: https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/pull/248